# Play realtime mp3 buffer in browser?

Tags: android, node.js, audio, socket.io

I am using `node.js` as a server to read mp3 from an android client using `socket.io` and then converting it to buffer. Once in the buffer I need to play the mp3 in in the browser (in realtime).

How can i do that?

Is this possible?

Comment: I have same problem!!! :(